# How to show values ONLY in php array?

Tags: php

I have a this:

```
$output = print_r($feedDrive, true);
```

But I just want the actual values, not the commas, or `[0] => etc`.

How can I do this?

Comment: one option: `implode ( ' ' , $feedDrive );` that would make the values space separated

Comment: [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is a function used for debug. Use `implode(', ', $feedDrive)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to generate a string that contains the values separated by comma and [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) to display it. Or use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to iterate over the array and process its (keys and) values in any way to want.

Comment: Don't understand why when I posted rtfms answer it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

There is [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop in php. You have to traverse the array.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value;
}
```

If you simply want to add commas between values, consider using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$string=implode(",",$array);
echo $string;
```